# How to get the displaying image on a ImageView

Tags: android

I have this scenario.
The app allows me to take a pic of something and save it to a sqlite db.
By now this app captures the image from the camera device and displays it on an ImageView.
The problem is how to obtain this image from the ImageView and parse it to a byte array

Comment: Refer to this link

[Byte Array image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212531/android-byte-to-image-in-camera-onpreviewframe)

or this 
[Storing image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684737/storing-images-in-drawable-folder-and-getting-the-image-to-load-by-using-the-ima)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable%28%29)?

It's simply

```
Drawable image = imageview.getDrawable();
```

to get the image.